# check if an input is lambda in Tcl

Tags: lambda, tcl, introspection

I get an argument in Tcl. How can I tell if it's a lambda function, other than using
`catch {apply $arg}`
?
Thanks

Comment: You should clarify: What is the problem? Is this about checking (a) whether a value can be submitted to `apply` (argument validation) successfully, (b) whether a value represents a valid (complete and "evaluable") anonymous function, or (c) whether the anonymous function executes (in a given context)?

Comment: M Safeer got it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tcl does not have a built-in type for lambda functions. `catch {apply $arg}` is the only option available. Any other thing that is out there will only be using some form of the `catch {apply $arg}`.

Comment: I suppose you can do some really basic sanity checking like making sure the argument has 2 or 3 elements.

Comment: If using a call of `apply`, I would consider using a throw-away safe interpreter: `set i [interp create -safe]; $i eval [list catch [list apply $arg]]`

Answer (score 3):

Lambdas are syntactically lists where the first element is a well-informed list of lists (usual rules for formal arguments to `proc`), the second element is a script (with a very wide rangle of syntax possible) and the third element (if supplied) is a namespace name (it defaults to `::`).

I'd check if you have a list of 2 or 3 elements where the first element is also a list (possibly empty). That should cover almost everything you'll ever see in practice.

Comment: Maybe add a validation of the second element (script) using a variant of [cmdSplit](https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/cmdSplit)?

Comment: You could validate the whole thing by seeing if `tcl::unsupported::getbytecode lambda` does anything sensible with it I guess...